# Particular asynchrony of requests with retrofit and rxJava

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java

I'm trying to upload image by chunks using retrofit like this:

```
rx.Observable.from(image.getChunks())
  .flatMap(chunk -> return api.upload(chunk))
  .subscribe(resp -> {}, err -> {} );
```

here `image.getChunks()` returns a `List<Chunk>` and `api` is a retrofit service that returns `rx.Observable`

Looks good but our back-end has a specific that first and last chunk should be first and last corresponding. In case of code I wrote it sends requests simultaneously so chunks are handled sometimes in wrong order.

I would like to do it with pure rx but I can't wrap my mind around rx to reach the desired result. Could someone help me to arrange [first](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/first.html), [last](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/last.html), [skip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html) and [skipLast](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skiplast.html) methods in right order ?

Thanks.

PS: or using methods I listed above is a wrong way to do this ?

UPD: I imagine code that looks something like this:

```
rx.Observable.from(image.getChunks())
    .first()
    .map(firstChunk -> return api.upload(firstChunk))
    .subscribe(
        resp -> {
            rx.Observable.from(image.getChunks())
                .skip(1)
                .skipLast(1)
                .flatMap(chunk -> return api.upload(chunk))
                .subscribe(
                    resp -> {}, 
                    err -> {},
                    () -> {
                        rx.Observable.from(image.getChunks())
                        .last(1)
                        .map(lastChunk -> {
                            api.upload(lastChunk).subscribe(
                                resp -> {
                                    //upload finished
                                },
                                err -> {}
                             )
                    }
                );
        },
        err -> {}
    );
```

I didn't try to run this code yet so I'm not sure it works. But problem here is that I do `rx.Observable.from(image.getChunks())` three times. I would like to do it once and than:

- consume first item
- wait until it will be uploaded
- consume all the rest items except the last one and upload them simultaneously
- wait until I receive response for each request
- consume the last item and upload it

Is it possible at all ?

UPD#2:

I realized over the weekend that code sample I wrote would not work as intended.
`onComplete()` with the last request will be triggered when all the items are consumed but not when all responses received.

Comment: Just replace `flatMap` call with a `concatMap` one. `concatMap` ensures all observables are executed sequentially.

Comment: Looks like problem is caught by the server not the client. Because sequence of requests sending is correct but as server receives a bunch of requests if handles them in wrong order. So I need to start all the requests, except the first and the last, after I receive response for the first chunk and start the last request after I receive all the responses sent before.

Comment: Do you mean only first and last chunk should be uploaded sequentially? And the rest of the chunks can be uploaded in any order? If so, this is how you can do it in `RxJava` - https://gist.github.com/nsk-mironov/59c8015fbd0870232142

Comment: I updated my question in order to be more clear

Comment: Ok, I see. Then then code I provided in my gist does exactly what you want.